# Can't get VMware player to isntall usb driver

Tags: vmware-player

I have a USB based oscilloscope that ran on XP. The driver wont install on Windows 7 64 bit, so I'm trying VMware player. Should I be able to install the driver in an XP VM? I can't get it to work.
Thanks, Brian

Comment: I don't see a reason i wouldn't work.  What exactly is not working about it?

Comment: The device is listed as "unknow device" in Device Manager in the VM. If I right click and select "Update driver", browse to the folder containing the inf and sys files, Windoes just comes back with "The driver was not installed - could not find the software to install this driver".